# Duplicate symbols when trying to add Google Sign In to iOS Firebase project

Tags: ios, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, google-signin

I'm trying to learn how to use Firebase in a new project I'm building. I added the `FirebaseCore`, `FirebaseDatabase`, `Firebase` and `GoogleToolboxForMac` to my project as per Google's instructions. (Manually as I'm no fan of Cocoapods).

All went fine and I tried to add a record to the database like this:

```
    FIRApp.configure()
    let dbRef = FIRDatabase.database().reference()
    dbRef.child("users/ABCDEF/username").setValue("drekka")
```

But got told

```
2017-07-02 20:15:18.409 Crux[19593] <Warning> 
    [Firebase/Database][I-RDB03812] setValue: or removeValue: at /users/ABCDEF/username failed: permission_denied
```

Did some reading and figured I need to provide some sort of credentials or login. Thought I'd try to implement a Google login as Firebase supports it. The docu there said to add Google Sign In. Which I did by adding the `GoogleAppUtilities`, `GoogleSingIn`, `GoogleSignInDependencies` and `GoogleSymbolUtilities` libraries.

However I got comflicts between `GoogleSignInDependencies` and `GoogleToolboxForMac`. So I took out `GoogleToolboxForMac` and got told there was missing symbols. So I tried taking out `GoogleSignInDependencies` and got told the same thing.

So I figure I've either something but I don't know what. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

Remove GoogleAppUtilities and GoogleSymbolUtilities.

If you're still having conflicts, post the output of `pod update` with your question.

BTW, you shouldn't need GoogleSignIn to make the database work. Likely there is a configuration problem on the Firebase console. Make sure the permissions are configured correctly.